# Too many connections on zookeper server

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, ambari, hdp

**Environment: HDP 2.6.4**

**Ambari – 2.6.1**

**3 zookeeper server**

**23.1.35.185  - is the IP of the first zookeeper server**

hi all,

In the first zookeeper server it seems that even after closing the connection to zookeeper is not getting closed,

which causes the maximum number of client connections to be reached from a host - we have maxClientCnxns as 60  in zookeeper config

As a result when a new application comes and tries to create a connection it fails.

Example when Connections are:

```
echo stat | nc 23.1.35.185 2181 

Latency min/avg/max: 0/71/399

Received: 3031 Sent: 2407

Connections: 67 

Outstanding: 622 

Zxid: 0x130000004d 

Mode: follower 

Node count: 3730
```

But after some time when connection comes to ~70 we see

```
echo stat | nc 23.1.35.185 2181

Ncat: Connection reset by peer.
```

And We can see also many CLOSE_WAIT

```
java      58936       zookeeper   60u  IPv6 381963738      0t0  TCP Zookeper_server.sys54.com:eforward->zookeper_server.sys54.com:44983 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

From the zookeeper log

```
2018-12-26 02:50:46,382 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@193]
    - Too many connections from /23.1.35.185 - max is 60
```

In the ambari we can see also

```
Connection failed: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer to zookeper_server.sys54.com.:2181
```

I must to say that this not happening on zookeeper servers 2 and 3

NOTE - if we increase the **maxClientCnxns** to 300 , its not help because after some time we get more the 300 connections ( CLOSE_WAIT ) and then we see from the log

```
2018-12-26 02:50:49,375 [myid:1] - WARN [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@193] - Too many connections from /23.1.35.187 - max is 300
```

so any hint why the connection are CLOSE_WAIT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLOSE_WAIT` means that the local end of the connection has received a `FIN` from the other end, but the OS is waiting for the program at the local end to actually close its connection.

The problem is your program running on the local machine is not closing the socket. It is not a `TCP` tuning issue. A connection can (and quite correctly) stay in `CLOSE_WAIT` forever while the program holds the connection open.

Once the local program closes the socket, the OS can send the FIN to the remote end which transitions you to `LAST_ACK` while you wait for the `ACK` of the FIN. Once that is received, the connection is finished and drops from the connection table (if your end is in `CLOSE_WAIT` you do not end up in the `TIME_WAIT` state).

There is a kernel level property to reuse the connection and reduce the `CLOSE_WAIT` time.

I suggest you to follow this tutorial http://www.linuxbrigade.com/reduce-time_wait-socket-connections/

This should probably solve your problem.